# Números gerados aleatoriamente com arrays repetem-se

Tags: c#

Procurei por todo o lado mas não encontrei algo que resolvesse o meu problema. De momento tenho isto:

```
int[] nums5 = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums5.Length; ++i)
        {
            int aleat5;
            do
            {
                aleat5 = r.Next(1, 99);
            } while (nums5.Contains(aleat5));
            lblNum.Text = aleat5.ToString();
```

No entanto, apesar dos números aleatórios aparecerem, estes repetem-se. Como resolvo isto?

Comment: Qual o resultado final que você deseja? Um array com 100 números diferentes?

Comment: Eu estou a fazer um jogo do Bingo e este array serve para os números que serão gerados automaticamente. Ou seja, quero que apareçam 100 números gerados de forma aleatória e que nenhum deles se repita!

Comment: Você pode preencher o array com o índice do loop (`nums5[i] = i + 1`) e depois embaralhar o array usando este algorítimo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/5775775. Isso irá gerar um array com números de 1 a 100 embaralhados.

Comment: Já tinha visto este código e não tinha chegado a esse resultado... irei tentar outra vez

Comment: Veja o código funcionando aqui: https://repl.it/repls/SameFrequentBlogclient

Comment: Outra possível solução é você armazenar os números gerados em um array e só aceitar novos números gerados desde que ainda não tenham sido previamente inseridos no array.

Comment: Era essa a minha ideia inicial. Só que depois não conseguia por os números do array numa label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentei, você pode preencher o array com o índice do loop (`nums5[i] = i + 1`) e depois embaralhar o array usando este algorítimo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/5775775. Isso irá gerar um array com números de 1 a 100 embaralhados.

O código ficaria assim:

```
int[] numeros = new int[100];

// Preenche o array com os numeros de 1 a 100
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++) {
  numeros[i] = i + 1;
}

// Embaralha os numeros (https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/5775775)
Random rng = new Random();
int n = numeros.Length;
while (n > 1) {
    int k = rng.Next(n--);
    int temp = numeros[n];
    numeros[n] = numeros[k];
    numeros[k] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Mas como é que eu depois ponho os números na label? Não posso fazer lblNum.text = numeros; ou lblNum.text = numeros.toString();

Comment: Usa `string.Join(", ", numeros)`

Comment: e é possível fazer com que os númeeros gerados sejam entre 1 e 100?

Comment: Estão a dar-me números demasiado grandes

Comment: Calcule o resto da divisão por 100 e some 1. (operador %)

Answer (score 1):

Uma ideia seria usar uma `List<int>` ou `Queue<int>` para guardar os numeros em vez de um array, porque posteriormente voce precisa remover o "elemento escolhido"..

Com uma `Queue<int>` que seria algo assim:

Declare a `Queue` fora de um metodo/função, normalmente antes de `public Form1()`

```
Queue<int> aleatorios;
```

Preencha a queue com valores, no sitio onde inicializa as variaveis ou no construtor do form (dentro de `public Form1(){}`)

```
var rnd = new Random();
aleatorios = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()));
```

Atribua um valor da queue (por ser que será o primeiro elemento) à label, ou seja, faça um `Dequeue`...

```
lblNum.Text = aleatorios.Dequeue().ToString();
```

o `Dequeue` automaticamente remove o primeiro elemento da `queue` que foi atribuido à label

Comment: Apesar de pensar que ia ficar bem, os números estão se repetindo

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mfqv56 como pode ver pela print

Comment: faz um print do codigo

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mfqw7o

Comment: tens que inicializar a queue no construtor do form dentro de: public Form1( { // aleatorios = new queue etc.... } tal como escrevi na resposta... ou dentro de um metodo/função que inicialize todas as variaveis/controlos... mas chame essa função tambem no construtor do form...

Comment: Já consegui, não olhei bem para o que tinha dito, peço desculpa!